# How to use app/Resources/public in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have got a `myRandomJavascriptLibrary.js` file. I want to put this file in location `app/Resources/public/js/`

But I do not know how can I access to this file in `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig`

I ran command `app/console assets:install web --symlink`

What is next?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add you global assets in `app/Resources`. They should go directly into the `web` folder. Command `assets:install` is only for bundles resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do, using assetic :

```
{% javascripts '../app/Resources/public/js/myRandom.js' %}
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```